# Material Data Table Sort and Pagination not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material Data Table but I cannot get the `sort` or `pagination` to work. I created a shared component which will be reused multiple times with different datasets (so different column names and such). The table header, and rows show up just fine (over 480 rows), but when I click the sort button nothing happens and the pagination buttons are disabled. However I cannot figure what I am doing wrong.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.4",
}
```

html

```
<div *ngIf="dataLoaded" class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns" [matColumnDef]="col">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{col}} </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">
          <!--  for mobile devices the columns collapse and each column is a row -->
          <span class="mobile-label">{{col}}:</span>
          {{data[col]}}
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
    <mat-paginator
      [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
      showFirstLastButtons>
    </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

component

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true})  paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true})       sort: MatSort;

dataLoaded = false;
dataSource;
displayedColumns; 
pageSizeOptions: number[] = [];
tableData = [
    {
        email: "brk@gmail.com"
        id: 1
        name: "B. Reurk"
    },
    {
        email: "john@gmail.com"
        id: 2
        name: "J. Smith"
    },
    // another 480 results which show in the table just fine
];

ngOnInit()
{
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableData);
    for (let i = 25; i <= this.tableData.length + 25; i += 25) {
    this.pageSizeOptions.push(i);
}
    this.displayedColumns = ['email', 'id', 'name'];
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

Comment: Paginator needs a length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to remove the `*ngIf` that wraps the table, which sucks because now I can't show a loading message, but it works!

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns" [matColumnDef]="col">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{col}} </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">
          <!--  for mobile devices the columns collapse and each column is a row -->
          <span class="mobile-label">{{col}}:</span>
          {{data[col]}}
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
    <mat-paginator
      [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
      showFirstLastButtons>
    </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not have a *ngIf  still can't get sorting working on mat-table. any ideas? thanks